# Novae versus supernovae type Ia

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-physics, supernova, white-dwarfs

Why are there any novae at all? My understanding is that once accretion on a white dwarf exceeds the Chandrasekhar limit, the white dwarf undergoes a supernova. Why then do some just simply go nova?

Comment: Does a nova progenitor reach Chandrasekhar limit?

Answer (score 3):

Type Ia supernovae may, or may not, be associated with the actual Chandrasekhar limit. More likely they result from the ignition of carbon/oxygen at high densities in white dwarfs close to the Chandrasekhar limit. The ignition may be spontaneous (pyconuclear reactions) or triggered by the ignition of lighter elements close to the surface of the white dwarf.

Novae occur because accreted material that is rich in hydrogen attains densities and temperatures that enable nuclear fusion. This is easier than igniting carbon and oxygen because of the much lower Coulomb repulsion. The ignition is abrupt and luminous because the accreted hydrogen is compressed in the surface layers to the point where the equation of state is governed by degeneracy pressure. Novae can occur on white dwarfs that are well below the Chandrasekhar mass.

Comment: this makes more intuitive sense to me than many of the other discussions on white dwarfs.  I wish this answer were easier to find.